# Windows system can't call ruby or gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

After I installed ruby, type ruby ​​or gem in cmd and there is no such command.

And I have added the installation path to the system environment.

Comment: Could you show your PATH variables? Both system and user. Did you confirm they are there or not? And just in case you didn't, you do have to restart a new shell for new PATH variables to take effect.

Comment: Just put ruby ​​on the system disk.

Comment: Ruby doesn't care if its on a "non-system" disk, and neither does an arbitrary value in your PATH variable. Once again, is it possible to see your PATH variables so that you can be helped? How did you add it? Is it in both system and user? Did you try restarting? If you want help, then some you need to offer some information.

Answer (score -1):

I did this, but it didn't work. But now it's done, because I installed ruby ​​on a non-system disk before, so there will be some strange problems.

Comment: This was not the problem, and incorrect as an answer. I, and many others, install Ruby on disks other than the primary `C:` drive when on Windows.